# UPDATE all tables on a database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm working on updating all the tables on a DB and I am having trouble getting the code correct. I was given the below code but as a previous solution but I am trying to use the `SP_msforeachtable` and can't get the correct format. And help with this would be wonderful. Here is the code:

```
USE TPP_DB
GO

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable

'SELECT @SQL = (
    SELECT ''
UPDATE ''' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id])) + ''.'''' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + '''
SET ''' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + '' = NULL
WHERE '' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + '' = ''''' 
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL'
```

Comment: Tag dbms used! (That doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: I was tying too fast and tagged enter and it put in SQL and Server. Thanks for the response 3 seconds after the post.

Comment: Only 3 seconds? That must be my personal record!

Comment: I realized my mistake right after I hit enter and I was fixing it when you commented and I wasn't able to add the three tags before you got to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' + Schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.'
       + t.NAME + ' SET ' + c.NAME + ' =NULL WHERE ' + c.NAME
       + ' ='''';'
FROM   sys.tables AS t
       INNER JOIN sys.columns c
               ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
--WHERE  c.NAME = 'ModifiedDate'
ORDER  BY Schema_name(t.schema_id),
          t.NAME;
```

Comment: This one works but I am needing to put this into a stored procedure and I need it to run without copy and pasting the output.

Comment: Nevermind I solved the problem with a cursor to parse through the tables.